# Having trouble positioning <ul> borders using ::before tags for HTML/CSS OrgChart

Tags: html, css

I've included a screenshot, CodePen link, and sample code below.

I'm trying to create an OrgChart that fits on a 1024px display and, because of its width, I've decided to stack the final pieces underneath to save width. This is working fine; however, my problems comes when drawing connectors for them. I'm having trouble understanding completely how to reverse some CSS and implement effective connector CSS.

A picture is the best explanation I can give because I'm not quite sure how to put it into words.[image: The issue highlighted with MS paint corrections]

NOTE: I am totally open to adding JavaScript if there's an easy fix. jQuery as well; however, I've had success simply sticking with HTML/CSS and I think I've just a hit a logic snag.

Here is the CodePen link: http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/zvgWjW?editors=110

HTML Layout (please see CodePen for more detailed view):

```
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
      <!-- DIRECTOR -->
      <li class="director">
        <a class="ss_button lvl-1" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class=
        "title">Director</span><br>
        <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
        <ul>
          <!-- ASSISTANT TO THE DIRECTOR -->
          <li>
            <a class="ss_button lvl-2" href="javascript:void(0);"><span
            class="title">Assistant to the Director</span><br>
            <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
            <ul>
              <!-- DEPUTY DIRECTOR -->
              <li class="deputydirector">
                <a class="ss_button lvl-2" href=
                "javascript:void(0);"><span class="title">Deputy
                Director</span><br>
                <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <ul class='last-ns'>
                      <!-- ASSOCIATE DIRECTOR -->
                      <li class="associatedirector1 off-fix">
                        <a class="ss_button lvl-3" href=
                        "javascript:void(0);"><span class="title">Associate
                        Director</span><br>
                        <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <ul>
                              <li>
                                <ul class='stacked'>
                                  <!-- CONSUMER LAWS & REGULATIONS -->
                                  <li>
                                    <a class='ss_button lvl-6' href=
                                    "javascript:void(0);"><span class=
                                    "title">Consumer Laws &amp;
                                    Regulations</span><br>
                                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                                    Manager</span></a>
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul> . . . [continues]
```

Full CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.tree {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
.tree li::before, .tree li::after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
}

/* Connectors CSS */
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.tree li a {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li a:hover {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

li a.just-line {
  display: none;
}

a.just-line + ul {
  padding-top: 74px;
}

a.just-line + ul:before {
  height: 74px;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tree a {
  width: 120px;
  height: 70px;
}

/* Accordion controls */

.ss_button { 
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.ss_content {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.ss_content {
  display: none;
}

.tree li a:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* temporary solution */

.off-fix {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}

.off-fix2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
}

/* Bottom row */

.stacked a {
  width: 100px;
}

.stacked li {
  position: relative;
  right: -15px;
  display: block;
}


/* PLAYGROUND - FIX AFTER */
.stacked li:last-child::before {
  border: 0 none;
}

.stacked li:after {
  border: 0 none;
}

/*::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
.stacked li::before, .stacked li::after {
  border-top: 0 none;
}

.stacked li:after {
  border-left: 0 none;
}

/* Connectors CSS */
.stacked li:only-child::after, .stacked li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.stacked li:first-child::before, .stacked li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.stacked li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 0 none;
}

.tree .last-ns ul::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
    height: 100px;
}
```

A note of the code: there will be some elements defined that don't make sense. I had to remove some of the more personal information from the OrgChart so my dropdown content has been removed as a result so, if you see useless elements, it may be a result of that.

Thanks for taking the time!